# QR reader with androidX and firebase

Tags: android, firebase, qr-code, androidx

I'm trying to do a QR reader with androidX and firebase, the thing is all the information about the changes is new and I'm having problems at making this app work and I think it is because of the build of the app. I'm tried different versions and libraries to use but the problem persists. One of the errors I got is

"Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel"

but there is probably some more (the debugging just mark that)

Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.qrtest3"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:18.0.1'
    implementation'com.wonderkiln:camerakit:0.13.1'
    implementation'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@aar'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Gradle Project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Main Activity

```
package com.example.android.qrtest3;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.FirebaseVision;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.barcode.FirebaseVisionBarcode;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.barcode.FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetector;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.barcode.FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.common.FirebaseVisionImage;
import com.wonderkiln.camerakit.CameraKitError;
import com.wonderkiln.camerakit.CameraKitEvent;
import com.wonderkiln.camerakit.CameraKitEventListener;
import com.wonderkiln.camerakit.CameraKitImage;
import com.wonderkiln.camerakit.CameraKitVideo;
import com.wonderkiln.camerakit.CameraView;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CameraView cameraView;
    Button btnDetect;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        cameraView.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        cameraView.stop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        cameraView = (CameraView) findViewById(R.id.cameraview);
        btnDetect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_detect);


        btnDetect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                cameraView.start();
                cameraView.captureImage();
            }

        });

        cameraView.addCameraKitListener(new CameraKitEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(CameraKitEvent cameraKitEvent) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(CameraKitError cameraKitError) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onImage(CameraKitImage cameraKitImage) {
                Bitmap bitmap = cameraKitImage.getBitmap();
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, cameraView.getWidth(),cameraView.getHeight(), false);
                cameraView.stop();

                runDetector(bitmap);
            }

            @Override
            public void onVideo(CameraKitVideo cameraKitVideo) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void runDetector(Bitmap bitmap) {
        FirebaseVisionImage image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap);
        FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions options = new FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions.Builder()
                .setBarcodeFormats(
                        FirebaseVisionBarcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE,
                        FirebaseVisionBarcode.FORMAT_PDF417
                )
                .build();
        FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetector detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionBarcodeDetector(options);

        detector.detectInImage(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(List<FirebaseVisionBarcode> firebaseVisionBarcodes) {
                        processResult(firebaseVisionBarcodes);
                    }
                })

                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

    }

    private void processResult(List<FirebaseVisionBarcode> firebaseVisionBarcodes) {
        for(FirebaseVisionBarcode item : firebaseVisionBarcodes)
        {
            int value_type = item.getValueType();
            switch (value_type)
            {
                case FirebaseVisionBarcode.TYPE_TEXT:
                {
                    android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setMessage(item.getRawValue());
                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
                break;

                case FirebaseVisionBarcode.TYPE_URL:
                {
                        //start browse url
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(item.getRawValue()));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                break;

                case FirebaseVisionBarcode.TYPE_CONTACT_INFO:
                {
                    String info = new StringBuilder("Name: ")
                            .append(item.getContactInfo().getName().getFormattedName())
                            .append ("\n")
                            .append ("Adress: ")
                            .append (item.getContactInfo().getAddresses().get(0).getAddressLines())
                            .append ("\n")
                            .append ("Email: ")
                            .append (item.getContactInfo().getEmails().get(0).getAddress())
                            .toString();
                    android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setMessage(info);
                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
                break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing was I needed to fully migrate to AndroidX (

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
```

importing the right things and changing

android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog to AlertDialog.